# ¿Cómo dices "leap day" en español?

Tags: traducción

Buscando en la RAE, revisé "bisiesto", luego busqué "día" y conseguí que el día que añadimos al año bisiesto (29 de Febrero) se le llama "día intercalar", pero nunca había escuchado esa expresión.

¿Cómo llaman ustedes a este día adicional que tenemos en los años bisiestos?

Comment: leap year, not leap day

Comment: Hi @Lambie, there's both, day and year... talking about day here.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Leap_day_in_the_Julian_and_Gregorian_calendars

Comment: It{s interesting to read the same article in Spanish Wikipedia. Whereever the English references "leap day" the Spanish uses "día extra".  That suggests that there is no common term for what you are looking for.  https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%C3%B1o_bisiesto

Comment: Arreglado. La Wikipedia ya indica que el día extra de una año bisiesto se denomína "día intercalar".

Answer (score 1):

Según la RAE, se dice "día intercalar".

https://dle.rae.es/d%C3%ADa#B9PesQo